# Is it correct to say that prime numbers don't exist on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

A prime number is defined as: "A non invertible and non zero numer $p$ of a ring $A$ is called a *prime number* if any time it divides a product of two numbers, it also divides one of the factors".
In $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ any number is divisible by any number, except for $0$. So take $7$ and $3\cdot 49$ for example. On $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ we have that $7|3\cdot49=3\cdot7\cdot7\land7|7\land7\nmid3$, so $7$ is a prime number on $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$.
But on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, $7$ divides both $3$ and $7$ (recall that in a ring $A$ a number $a$ is said do divide a number $b$ if there's a number $c\in A$ s.t. $b=a\cdot c$).
So, having said that, can I say that prime numbers don't exist on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: A field has no "non-invertible, non-zero elements."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q$ do not contain any prime elements, but the reasoning you have provided does not seem correct to me. If $R$ is a commutative ring, we say that $r\in R$ is a *prime element* if the following three conditions hold:

1. $r\neq0.$
2. $r$ is not a unit.
3. For all $a,b\in R$, if $r$ divides $ab$, then $r$ divides $a$ or $r$ divides $b.$

In the case of $\mathbb R$, the element $7$ satisfies both (1) and (3). However, $7$ is a unit, so it does not satisfy (2). The same comments apply to $\mathbb Q$.

More generally, if $K$ is a field, then $K$ does not contain any prime elements. This is because, if $x\in K$, then either $x=0$ or $x\neq0$. If $x=0$ then, by definition, $x$ is not prime. If $x\neq0$, then by the definition of a field, $x$ is a unit, so again $x$ is not prime.

Comment: Why is $7$ considered a unity? From what I understand a unity on a ring $A$ is an element $e$ s.t. $e\cdot x=x\cdot e= x\;\forall x\in A$.

Comment: @A.FariasRiba: In ring theory, the term "unit(y)" is unfortunately used in more than one way. In this context, saying that $7$ is a unit means that $7$ is invertible, i.e. there is an $r\in\mathbb R$ such that $7\cdot r=r\cdot 7 = 1$. It *does not* mean that $7$ is the multiplicative identity element, $1$.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: @A.FariasRiba: No problem! By the way, the reason I thought your reasoning was incorrect is this: since $7$ divides $3\cdot 49$, if $7$ is prime then $7$ must divide $3$ or $7$ must divide $49$. This is true: $7$ divides $3$ *and* $7$ divides $49$, so it is indeed the case that $7$ divides $3$ or $7$ divides $49$. (In mathematics, the term "or" is always used in the sense of "one or the other, or both.") The only thing stopping $7$ from being a prime is the fact that it is a unit. Please let me know if I misunderstood your argument.

Comment: You understood my argument correctly. I can see why my argument does not hold. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @A.FariasRiba: I am happy to help. Let me offer one more comment: the reason that units are excluded from being "prime elements" is because they satisfy condition (3) in a very boring way. If $r$ is a unit of a commutative ring, then it divides *every* element (prove this!). This causes with prime factorisation, for instance: in a UFD (if you don't know what a UFD is, just pretend it is $\mathbb Z$ for now), we want every prime decomposition of an element to be of the same length.

Comment: But if we allowed the units $1$ and $-1$ to be prime in $\mathbb Z$, then we would have factorisations of different lengths: for instance, we could write $10=2\cdot 5$, but we could also write $10=2\cdot 5\cdot (-1)\cdot (-1)$.

Comment: That's a very good explanation. Thank you.